# preConditionRule

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Please see the following manifest. Suppose that we want to start the following content package for the first time. Which activity should be delivered when we click the start button in the Learning Management System (LMS)?

```
<organization identifier = "OB-03c">
    <title>Content Package 1</title>
    <item identifier = "activity_1" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 1</title>
        <imsss:sequencing>
            <imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:preConditionRule>
                    <imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleCondition operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown"/>
                    </imsss:ruleConditions>
                    <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                </imsss:preConditionRule>
            </imsss:sequencingRules>
            <imsss:objectives>
                <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                    <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-3" />
                </imsss:primaryObjective>
            </imsss:objectives>
        </imsss:sequencing>
    </item>
    <item identifier = "activity_2">
        <title>Activity 2</title>
        <item identifier = "activity_3">
            <title>Activity 3</title>
            <item identifier = "activity_4" identifierref = "SEQ01">
                <title>Activity 4</title>
            </item>
            <item identifier = "activity_5" identifierref = "SEQ01">
                <title>Activity 5</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:sequencingRules>
                        <imsss:preConditionRule>
                            <imsss:ruleConditions>
                                <imsss:ruleCondition condition = "satisfied"/>
                            </imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                        </imsss:preConditionRule>
                    </imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:objectives>
                        <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-1" />
                        </imsss:primaryObjective>
                    </imsss:objectives>
                </imsss:sequencing>
            </item>
            <item identifier = "activity_6" identifierref = "SEQ01">
                <title>Activity 6</title>
            </item>
            <imsss:sequencing>
                <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
                <imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:preConditionRule>
                        <imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleCondition condition = "satisfied"/>
                        </imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                    </imsss:preConditionRule>
                </imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:objectives>
                    <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ" satisfiedByMeasure = "true">
                        <imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>0.6</imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-3" readSatisfiedStatus = "false" writeSatisfiedStatus = "true" />
                    </imsss:primaryObjective>
                </imsss:objectives>
            </imsss:sequencing>
        </item>
        <item identifier = "activity_7" identifierref = "SEQ01">
            <title>Activity 7</title>
            <imsss:sequencing>
                <imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:preConditionRule>
                        <imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleCondition operator = "not" condition = "satisfied"/>
                        </imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                    </imsss:preConditionRule>
                </imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:objectives>
                    <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-2" />
                    </imsss:primaryObjective>
                </imsss:objectives>
            </imsss:sequencing>
        </item>
        <item identifier = "activity_8" identifierref = "SEQ01">
            <title>Activity 8</title>
            <imsss:sequencing>
                <imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:preConditionRule>
                        <imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleCndition operator = "not" condition = "satisfied"/>
                            <imsss:ruleCondition operator = "not" condition = "objectiveStatusKnown" referencedObjective = "obj1"/>
                        </imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                    </imsss:preConditionRule>
                </imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:objectives>
                    <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-2" />
                    </imsss:primaryObjective>
                    <imsss:objective objectiveID = "obj1" >
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "gObj-OB03-3" />
                    </imsss:objective>
                </imsss:objectives>
            </imsss:sequencing>
        </item>
        <imsss:sequencing>
            <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
        </imsss:sequencing>
    </item>
    <item identifier = "activity_9" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 9</title>
    </item>
    <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
    </imsss:sequencing>
</organization>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity 4 will be delivered first. Explanation:
1. Activity 1 will be skipped because of the preConditionRule objectiveStatusKnown.
2. Activity 2 is parent. 
3. Activity 3 is parent.
4. Activity 4 is the first available leaf and its parent (Activity 3) has the "flow" set to true.
To help you understand how your manifet works, download Visual Manifest 2004 from http://www.naseelco.com. It displays your manifest visually. To test your manifest, you may download LMS2004 from the same website. It's a fully functional LMS but it works on your local machine without a server. Below are snapshots for your manifest loaded in Visaul Manifest and LMS2004.

[image: Visual Manifest]

[image: LMS2004]